# Some apps only work on wifi

Tags: applications, wi-fi, mobile-data

I have a few apps on my phone that for some reason only work on wifi. It is an email client and a public transportation app.
I tried reinstalling the apps, clear cache and data, clear cache, and data on Google Play Services, resetting network settings but nothing seems to work. Is there any way I can make them work on mobile data as well?

EDIT
As suggested, I'm including a few more details. The affected apps are [Microsoft Outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook&hl=ro) and [InfoTB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.stbsa&hl=ro).
I am Romanian, my carrier is Vodafone, my phone is a Samsung Galaxy 10e running on Android 10.

Comment: Without knowing anything more specific, mobile providers can block some links or protocols for whatever reasons. Using VPN on the mobile *might* work, but YMMV.

Comment: I added the details you guys asked.